# Why the classes loaded by different custom classloaders can't invoke each other

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

Why they are isolated to each other and can only use class loaded by themself and their parents though they are all stored in method area which is shared

Comment: They certainly can--A lot of `java.lang` classes are loaded by the system classloader, yet can be referenced from classes loaded by your application classloader.

Comment: You have to setup proper delegation. And that can be hard.

Comment: What do you mean by method area?

Comment: I mean what is the theory of isolation in loading class by different custom classloaders

Comment: Delegation. A ClassLoader usually delegates to an other ClassLoader, usually the parent class loader.

Comment: If I want to use different implementations of the same class in same application (same JVM), then I would do that via custom ClassLoaders. This is where isolation helps.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn, Thank you, I understand it, The class loader will try to load other class referenced by the primary class, use the delegation pattern of parents

Answer (score 0):

Classes loaded in different branches of a class loader tree cannot call each other directly as they don't have access to the classes or interfaces in branches they don't have.  What they can do is use reflection, or call via a common interface or superclass.